# The file "PhotoUploader" could not be viewed as you dont have permission to view it

Tags: ios7, github, xcode6, flickr

I downloaded PhotoUploader from github to integrate flicke in xcode, link is below

https://github.com/bobbypage/DPFlickr

Now I am trying to run the PhotoUploader example project in my xocde 6.Project snapshot is attached here. Please help me.

[image: Snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by myself:

1. Perform changes to upgrade the project to xcode 6 version.
2. Delete libz.1.2.3.dylib framework and then add libz.dylib